# why heap space is smaller than sum of young and survivors after young gc?

Tags: g1gc

My jvm options:

```
-verbose:gc -Xmx200M -Xmn40M -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:NewSize=40m -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
```

The following is gc log:

```
Desired survivor size 2621440 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 1)
- age   1:        792 bytes,        792 total
, 0.0012861 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 0.4 ms, GC Workers: 8]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 120214.2, Avg: 120214.3, Max: 120214.3, Diff: 0.2]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 0.2, Max: 0.3, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 1.3]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.3]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 0.6, Max: 1, Diff: 1, Sum: 5]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.4]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1, Diff: 0, Sum: 8]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 0.2, Avg: 0.3, Max: 0.4, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 2.2]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 120214.5, Avg: 120214.5, Max: 120214.6, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.1 ms]
   [Other: 0.7 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.4 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.2 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.0 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.0 ms]
   [Eden: 39.0M(39.0M)->0.0B(39.0M) Survivors: 1024.0K->1024.0K Heap: 39.9M(200.0M)->670.6K(200.0M)]
 [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.01, real=0.00 secs]
```

My question is why heap space(670.6K) is smaller than sum of(0+1024=1024) eden and survivors from the gc log `[Eden: 39.0M(39.0M)->0.0B(39.0M) Survivors: 1024.0K->1024.0K Heap: 39.9M(200.0M)->670.6K(200.0M)]`